# Spring Security Forrward fro one login page to another

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.2 annotations.

I configured two HttpSecurity to secure /admin/** (ADMIN role) and /** (USER role). Each secured section has its own login page.

At startup the user is directed OK to login page of USER. 
In this page there is a link to a secured page of ADMIN, so my thought was that when clicking on that link the user will be directed to the ADMIN login page. BUT it seems that the browser stays on USER login page.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

check your logs, turn them on in log4j.properties file if you cant see anything.

Probably spring security consider you as an authorized user but without required ADMIN role.

Try to log out and type admin page url directly in your browser - do you get admin login page?